# XMPPFramework - "<not-authorized>" when logging into Openfire server

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I installed Openfire server in my mac and did all the configuration. When i trying to connect it thro XMPP Protocol in the sense am getting bellow error log.

```
RECV: <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>
```

and also i note that in login response am getting username as null check bellow log

```
decoded response: username="(null)",realm="172.16.0.162",nonce="EFYJmP/oVfVKnhvuenmxVEBwH7VzYMET5j1cUqJ/",cnonce="DE5E4A14-3B6E-4239-B6AB-0B8BC1D75539",nc=00000001,qop=auth,digest-uri="xmpp/nivas",response=a64dcc45fef55811788d8784546baf29,charset=utf-8
```

Can any one tell me am i doing anything wrong here and any suggestion.??

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to log in with? Your own application or something like Adium or Psi? If it's your own code, please post the relevant parts

Comment: no am trying to execute with XMPP Sample(downloaded from google codes) for a mock chat fuction creation with local host. i had created a useraccount in openfire admin console am trying to login with that created user account.

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to XMPPFramework, an Objective-C library. Please post the relevant code from your Xcode project - where you login to the XMPP server. It's more likely to be an issue there than with Openfire itself

Comment: now i fixed this problem.. thing is that the username format which passed is wrong.. i sent username like "username@hostname" then its started to working..

Answer (score 4):

For users using iOS's XMPPFramework, and receiving this message:

`<failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized/></failure>`

Append your server domain name to the back of each user IDs, like so:

`keithoys@openfire`